# mysql user defined variables as derived table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an array with containing elements myArr[1,2,3,4]. I want to use it as a derived table in select statement. Is it possible

```
"SELECT * FROM myArr as table1"
```

Comment: This question is very, very unclear. Please take a look at the [ask] page, this will help you because better questions will get better answers

Comment: My question: "Is it possible to use php array as a derived table in mysql query." To make it bit more clear say my code is like this:           $myArray= array(1,3,4,5,6);

mysql_connect("localhost","root","pswd");
$sql="SELECT p.* FROM $myArray p";
$result=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql));

print_r($result);

Comment: please edit your question because code in comments is going to get lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM
(
  SELECT 1 value UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 
) table1
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/24481)** demo

You can easily produce it in php like this using [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```php
$myArr = array(1,2,3,4);

$sql  = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT ';
$sql .= implode(' value UNION ALL SELECT ', $myArr);
$sql .= ') table1';
```

Here is **[Codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/JeLttg)** demo

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.* 
FROM (
   SELECT *
   FROM myArr
) AS table1
```

Comment: @Marc B thanks for this. Yes i am trying to use php array myArr[] as what you have used in sub-select statement but it generates SQL error. Please help  ..

Comment: you can't use php data structures in an sql context. e.g. `"SELECT * FROM $php_array"` is not going to work. you need to convert your PHP into sql equivalents.